# pthread_attr_setaffinity_np does not return or throw an error

Tags: c++, pthreads

I'm trying to start a couple of threads, each on it's own core (4 cores -> 4 threads e.g.).
Pin the threads to their cores looks like:

```
pthread_t thread_objs[cpu_count];
pthread_attr_t attr;
cpu_set_t cpus;
pthread_attr_init(&attr);

for (unsigned int t = 0; t < cpu_count; t++) {
    pthread_t new_thread;
    CPU_ZERO(&cpus);
    CPU_SET(t, &cpus);
    if(pthread_attr_setaffinity_np(&attr, sizeof(cpu_set_t), &cpus)) {
        std::cerr << "fatal: could not set affinity" << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }
    if(pthread_create(&thread_objs[t], &attr, start_routine, NULL)) {
        std::cerr << "fatal: thread creation failed" << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }
}

for (unsigned int t = 0; t < cpu_count; t++) {
    pthread_join(thread_objs[t], NULL);
}
```

Ẁhile testing, I figured out that the first call of `pthread_attr_setaffinity_np` never returns. I waited several hours, but nothing happened.

Used  `glibc` is `ldd (Ubuntu GLIBC 2.23-0ubuntu9) 2.23`.

Comment: The first call should set your affinity to cpu zero, right? Is something else already running there with higher priority? Are you running this in a cgroup? Anything else that could affect scheduling and affinity? If the call never returns, presumably your thread isn't getting scheduled any more ...

Comment: The posted snippet is called from the main thread, which is creating other threads, one for each core. There is no other thread, which could affect scheduling and affinity. Why should the calling thread never be scheduled again?

Comment: FWIW, it works for me, on Ubuntu 14. I have 12 cores, and as long as cpu_count is lower than 13, all is fine. If I increase cpu_count over 12, pthread_create fails (since affinity is set to a non-existing CPU, probably).

Comment: Crazy, tested it on three different machines - all with the described result.

Comment: _no other thread which could affect_ you mean **nothing** is running on this machine? No other process, no kernel threads? How are you starting the program?

Comment: What happens if you start the thread and then move _that_ to its target affinity, instead of migrating the main thread multiple times? What happens when you run under `strace -f`?  What happens if you run from `1 ... cpu_count` instead?

Comment: I will add an answer with my working code, try to compile and run that and see if setaffinity blocks, I cannot see why it should.

Comment: Can you post a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and include the commands used to compile & link the program. Also details on the platform(s) you ware running on.

Answer (score 1):

Below I post my code (basically the same as in the question), it works for me on Ubuntu (actually Goobuntu) 14 with a 12-core machine. Reduce nr of CPUs variable to get it to run on a machine with fewer cores.

```
#include <pthread.h>

#include <unistd.h>

#include <iostream>

using std::cerr;
using std::cout;

const int cpu_count = 12;
pthread_t thread_objs[cpu_count];
pthread_attr_t attr;
cpu_set_t cpus;

void* start_routine(void*)
{
    sleep(2);

    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    pthread_attr_init(&attr);

    for (unsigned int t = 0; t < cpu_count; t++) {
        pthread_t new_thread;
        CPU_ZERO(&cpus);
        CPU_SET(t, &cpus);

        cout << "Nr of set cpus in set: " << CPU_COUNT(&cpus) << '\n';

        if(pthread_attr_setaffinity_np(&attr, sizeof(cpu_set_t), &cpus)) {
            std::cerr << "fatal: could not set affinity" << std::endl;
            return 1;
        }
        if(pthread_create(&thread_objs[t], &attr, start_routine, NULL)) {
            std::cerr << "fatal: thread creation failed" << std::endl;
            return 1;
        }
    }

    for (unsigned int t = 0; t < cpu_count; t++) {
        pthread_join(thread_objs[t], NULL);
    }

    cout << "Joined all threads, ending!\n";
}
```